# Python Pptx - Modifying existing table

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am trying to modify the existing table using the Python Pptx library. I am able to add rows and columns. But I am facing two problems

1. Not able to edit the table after generating the ppt in windows MS
   office PowerPoint presentation
2. Not able to decrease/increase the row size logically in the code

Code:

```
def add_row(table)
    new_row = deepcopy(table._tbl.tr_lst[-1])
    row = _Row(self.new_row,table)
    setattr(row,'height', 50000)
    .....   
    table._tbl.append(new_row)
```

I am expecting the `setattr` to increase/decrease the row size. But it is not working as expected. Also editing a table manually in MS PowerPoint is not working.